# Maui Android App with BlazorWebView selecting "Clear Storage" breaks application

Tags: android, .net, blazor, maui

What the title says, I've created a Maui App with a Blazor webview, it's kind of great. But on android if I goto app info and "Clear Storage" it nukes the app and it stops working. On the basis that my user data is 500kb and it's reporting 100MB of user storage I'm going to guess that it's clearing the all assets and images out when you hit "Clear Storage" - has anyone found a workaround for this, or am I doing something daft?

Comment: What do you mean by "Clear Storage" as in the Android app management thing? Is this with just a File > New project or do you have some custom code? Would you be able to show me a (public) project that shows this behavior?

Comment: Yes, in the "App info" on Android for the App, you have settings options for Notifications/Storage etc. If you select "Storage and cache", then select "Clear Storage" (on older android devices this is entitled "Clear User Data"), it should clear out the user data and leave you with a freshly installed app. However, it says the App is using 100Mb of data (incorrect) and clearing it out leaves an App which doesn't work. It's reproducable with the default Maui Blazor Webview app.

Comment: Yeah so I'm wondering if we put stuff in the wrong place that is needed for Blazor and/or BlazorWebView and that gets wiped by this action effectively breaking your app. I'm going to try this now and if I see it probably open a bug on the repo :)

Comment: Dev community in action - love it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments I poked around in this a little and was about to open an issue or ask colleagues when I suddenly realized: maybe this is just a debug thing.

When you put a debug build on your device and hit "Delete Data" on your app it stops working. What triggered me was that the data also was pretty big to begin with (60mb for a File > New Project app).

When you switch to a release build, the size decreases drastically and also this problem then goes away. I haven't checked, but my assumption is that we add files to our app data for debugging purposes that are removed by hitting "Delete Data" however, an app in release build (and thus apps that you distribute) are not affected.

For completeness, this isn't just affecting .NET MAUI Blazor apps but also .NET MAUI apps, Xamarin.Android apps and Xamarin.Forms apps.

Comment: I'll come back and check/mark complete once I can get my app to work in "Release" - currently it just crashes.  It looks to be a linker issue (a known issue, but the workaround of adding  <AndroidLinkMode>None</AndroidLinkMode> just stops my project from building ...).

Comment: Restarting Vs fixed the build issue (if only I tried that 3 hours earlier!). Can confirm you're right, the release build works as expected. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Perfect, glad to be of service!